# Best word for "Dr. Einstein, <blank> of the theory of Special Relativity."

Tags: word-choice

What is the best word to describe the creator of a scientific theory? As in:

> Einstein was the `_____` of the theory of Special Relativity.

*Creator*, *author*, *originator*, and *inventor* are possibilities, but which is the most appropriate/accepted term?

---

**EDIT:**

“Father” seems to be the best fit for the example I gave, but is less apt for theories not as widely recognized as relativity or evolution. What would be the term for a less renowned scientist who has proposed a more controversial theory?

Comment: Searching through the first few pages of results in Google Books for ["Einstein/Darwin/Newton/etc. was the" "of the theory"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Einstein+was+the%22+%22of+the+theory%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) confirms my suspicion that Anglophones in general don't often use OP's specific construction in this context (I didn't notice a single written instance where my two "quoted" search strings appeared either side of a suitable candidate noun).

Comment: What about the construction “Einstein, `_____` of the theory of Special Relativity, was a really smart dude.”?

Comment: Will, that is *precisely* the same construction, is it not? This is @FumbleFingers' point; that construction is uncommon.  To comment on your construction, it would be *Einstein was a really smart dude. He developed the Theory of Relativity.

Comment: @medica: As the comments under your own answer would suggest, part of the problem here may be that we're not really sure exactly *how* to characterise the "role" of the leading inceptor of a major new theory/paradigm. Firstly because they rarely achieve such feats in complete isolation and secondly because we're never sure if they "created" or "discovered" the new knowledge. There's more of the former in *creating **[the theory of]** relativity*, and more of the latter in *discovering **[the existence of]** DNA*, say.

Comment: @medica, Yes, but the construction’s usage in that sentence is probably more common than its usage in my original example, which may explain why FumbleFinger's Google search didn't return many results.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The existence of DNA was known before the duo took it up; Linus Pauling and Crick/Watson et al. were in a heated competition to learn its **structure**. they discovered (uncovered) its structure, as Einstein worked out the needed  principles to support the theory.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this is indeed the problem. The establishment of a new scientific theory is somewhere between creating a painting and discovering a new species; in this particular case, I think it's fair to say Einstein created the theory.

Comment: @medica, the reason I think so is mainly that it's difficult to say where the theory came from if you rule out people (whereas the phenomenon itself certainly didn't come from people).

Comment: Father would be problematic if the scientist were female.  Inventor or discoverer will trigger the philosophical arguments over whether mathematic/scientific "thingies" are discovered or invented.  Clunky as it is, I think "first to describe" might be the least objectionable.

Comment: @schodge, Yes, I agree it's not ideal. And you're completely right about “inventor” triggering philosophical debate, as evidenced by comments on this and other answers `:)`. However, “first to describe” would be referring to the phenomenon; I'm looking specifically for a term referring to the *theory*.

Comment: @Will First to propose?

Comment: @schodge, that works!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Einstein was the "**father**" of the theory of Special Relativity.

> *Charles Darwin was the [**father**](http://www.nytimes.com/top/reference/timestopics/people/d/charles_robert_darwin/index.ctx?query=MOVIES&field=des&match=exact) of the theory of natural selection*.

Comment: I'm sure it's not exactly the kind of word OP was looking for, but it seems like the best fit to me. I'll also just say I found more instances of ["Einstein, the father of the theory..."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Einstein+the+father+of+the+theory%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books than the total for all variations using OP's four suggested alternatives.

Comment: This is a good answer, though I'd also be interested in what the term is for someone who is still alive and where the theory is not fully accepted by most scientists in the field.

Comment: @Will, there is no implication in this phrasing that Einstein is dead. For a parallel, consider Noam Chomsky who is still alive and has been called the father of modern linguistics for many years.

Comment: @Will an "original?"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, point taken, but hopefully my meaning was clear enough.

Comment: @Will Also, if something is not accepted by **most** scientists in the field, then it's very difficult to even call it a theory. It's more of an hypothesis.

Comment: The problem I have with it is that this is a gendered word; many people would balk at being described as the ''mother'', ''father'', ''queen'', ''prince'', etc.

Comment: @Cruncher, I disagree. My dictionary has the definition of *theory* as “a supposition or a system of ideas intended to explain something, esp. one based on general principles independent of the thing to be explained”. There is nothing there to indicate that a theory need be generally accepted (*e.g.* a conspiracy *theory*).

Comment: @Will In science, the word theory is much stronger than your everyday use of "I have a theory about that!". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_theory

Comment: @Cruncher (1) True, the meaning of the word theory is different in scientific contexts than the everyday usage. However, “A theory is not the same as a hypothesis. A theory provides an explanatory framework for some observation, and from the assumptions of the explanation follows a number of possible hypotheses that can be tested in order to provide support for, or challenge, the theory.” ([Wikipedia](http://goo.gl/n1cefJ))

Comment: @Cruncher (2) A theory need not be widely accepted to qualify as a theory. For example, Lamarck's theory of [soft inheritance](http://goo.gl/dTeV1a) is a theory, but it is not accepted by most scientists in the field.

Comment: I agree with others who dislike this word choice for being gendered. I would not force the usage of a word in such a sentence because I don't feel there are any natural sounding alternatives at all. Instead I'd write for example: `Einstein, who authored the theory of Special Relativity`. In this way, you're capturing the fact they *discovered* the theory, respecting the often-held belief the rules they wrote about already existed, rather than being *created* by them.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the professors I know wouldn't refer to themselves as inventors, creators, or any such word denoting actual creation of a physical phenomenon. They see themselves as founders rather than creators; they don't invent the rules, they merely describe them. For that reason, I would consider the following over a synonym for "create." Note that I think a verb would probably work better than a noun, but given the placement of the blank and the words you provided...

*Founder*, *pioneer*, *presenter*, *developer*.

But when they are described by others who don't reflect the modesty of the founders themselves, *inventor* is the word I see most often.

Comment: I don't think you can be a pioneer of a theory, you can be a pioneer *in the field of* something. But *the founder* of such and such theory, fits in quite well imo.

Answer (score 7):

I would insert 'formulator' into your blank space, on the grounds that it is probably the best choice out of a problematic set of possibilities (as is evident from the comments elsewhere in this thread). The nouns 'proposer' and 'propounder' are also possible, but don't sound very natural.

On the other hand, the associated verbs all sound perfectly idiomatic to me. So given the option, I would prefer to reword your sentence slightly:

> It was Einstein who {formulated / proposed / propounded} the theory of Special Relativity.

Answer (score 5):

Developer and discoverer are possibilities; Einstein established the theory of relativity, rather than invented or created it.

Comment: Establishing a mathematical theory of physics **is** creating and inventing it. There was no mathematical theory of relativity before Einstein.

Comment: Relativity existed before Einstein discovered it. He did not *create* relativity; did he *create* its theory? That is debatable; he uncovered it, he developed it, he discovered it. Scientists use a different language than linguists, despite your objections. Watson and Crick uncovered/discovered the structure of DNA. Makers create the laws that govern the universe. Finally, few people discover things independently of scientists before them; developer is probably the most accurate descriptor for people who prove a theory proposed (even in part) by someone before them.

Comment: I would say that Einstein did not create relativity *per se*, but he did create the *theory* of relativity. At least to me, the meaning of the word “theory” is the body of human knowledge that describes or explains a phenomenon. Humans create theories, but not necessarily the phenomena they explain.

Comment: @John: The exact status of the discoverer/creator is a moot point when it comes to the stuff *mathematicians* get up to these days. I may be mistaken, but I suspect the mathematicians themselves are more likely to think they *create* new paradigms, where the general public assume they're simply *discovering* principles which were always "out there" waiting to be formalised. In a way, the opposite of *sculptors* (we usually say they *create* sculptures, but the "carvers & chiselers" sometimes say they're simply uncovering what was always in the stone/wood/etc.).

Comment: @Will - to create implies doing something *de novo*. Einstein did not exist in a vacuum. He relied on the work of his predecessors, whether they were right or wrong (ruling out the incorrect). The definition of *Theory* itself is perceived differently among scientists and laymen. Newton famously stated "If I have seen further it is by standing on ye sholders of Giants." And he was not even the first to make that statement.

Comment: Formulated is probably the best word for this. Interestingly, it's disputed how much credit should go to Einstein in formulating the two theories: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_priority_dispute

Comment: Just to stir the pot a little: the relativity principle had been around since Galileo, it's just that it was assumed that wave phenomena needed special handling *vis a vis* it's medium. Nor was Einstein the first to develop the mathematical description of the symmetry that forms the core of the theory (that was Lorentz). Einstein collected several ideas together with a bold postulate, took them serious, derived a bunch of consequences, and (ever so tentatively) showed the results to the rest of the physics world.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my experience has actually been the opposite so far. Most mathematicians I know or have read about would say that studying math has convinced them that they're discovering pieces of mathematics, rather than creating them. Of course, this is a longstanding debate in the philosophy of mathematics, and I'm not making a claim either way—but I will claim that mathematicians tend to side with the “discovered” camp.

Comment: The theory of relativity is a way of describing and understanding certain physically observable phenomena. It is not the phenomena it describes, which are fundamental aspects of the universe we live in. So Einstein did create the theory, although, of course, he did not create what it describes.

Comment: @DominicCronin - Einstein would be the first to tell you (if he could) that he discussed his theory with others, and used their work in his own. He did not create his theory *de novo*. He was wise and humble enough to credit others, and audacious enough to disagree. See Lemaitre's Big Bang theory, with which Einstein disagreed. They all bounce ideas off of each other. If we are intellectually honest, we realize how little we actually create.

Comment: @medica - he did create Einstein's theories of relativity. Maybe he stood on the shoulders of giants (or was that Newton? :-) but we credit him with creating his own theory. In the context of science, that robs no-one.

Answer (score 3):

"Creator" seems fine, and originator ok, but I dislike the other two.

"Creator" seems appropriate.  "X created Y" implies that prior to X's creative action Y did not exist and afterwards it did.  Causing a theory to come into being may involve rearranging existing parts (mathematical operators, and paradigms that help understand formalisms at an intuitive level) and helping physicists understand it.

"Author" seems inappropriate.  "X authored Y" implies that the significant part of the act was finding the right terms (broadly interpreted) to convey something.  That was not the case here.  The idea itself was novel.

"Originator" seems somewhat appropriate.   "X originates from Y" implies that without Y there would be no X, but after the originating event X is no longer dependent on Y for continued existence.  Many other words convey the former, but "originator" seems a poor choice unless you really want to convey the latter.

"Inventor" seems inappropriate.  Inventors create inventions and "invention" is usually a physical device or process of some sort.  It seems odd to use the word invention for a set of closed-form expressions and accompanying explanatory framework.

---

If what you wish to convey is that Einstein had an idea (a concept), did much of the hard work to formalize it, and presented it to the community of physicists, then maybe "conceiver."

Comment: I would actually prefer "originator" over "creator" because of the idea that a major, well-accepted scientific theories is a fundamental truth not a creative enterprise, but I agree with all your other comments.

Comment: @AmeliaBR, I disagree with "is not a creative enterprise" because it's not obvious to me that finding a way to make a fundamental truth accessible is not a creative enterprise, so creativity and fundamentality seem to be separable concerns.  If by "fundamental truth" you mean "true analytic statement" then I also disagree because I'm not convinced that the synthetic/analytic distinction is coherent.  Third, theories are descriptive, not proscriptive so one could create many descriptive theories that equally accurately track some underlying proscriptive natural law.

Answer (score 2):

Since science is a cooperative effort, and many different scientists contribute to a theory, in cases like this I would use the word "original", as in

> Albert Einstein was the original author (contributor, developer, ...) of the theory of Special Relativity.

Comment: Why not "Albert Einstein was the originator of the theory..."?

Comment: In this context, "originator" is not a clearly defined word. For example, Michelson & Morley, performed an experiment that was the basis of the SR. Lorentz and Fitzgerald provided a formula for the length contraction in said experiment. Both things arguably "originated" the theory, although none of the above scientists initially develop the theory...

Answer (score 2):

- Discovered (incorrect)

What is really discovered is the underlying phenomena, not the theory itself.

- Invented (incorrect)

The purpose of a theory is to **describe** phenomena that already exists in nature. This is distinct from an invention, which rather a creation that originates more completely within the author's mind.

- **Formulated**

A scientific theory like this one is neither invented nor discovered. The theory only "spells out", or explains something that already exists in nature. Therefore, formulated seems like an appropriate choice.

Also, as others have pointed out, science is a collaborative effort, and Einstein is rather the scientist who is most popularly associated with the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Scientists themselves find it hard to determine whether they "invent" theories or "discover" them. Surely Darwin's theory of evolution was invented, since it's a qualitative birds-eye view of evolution. And surely the continent of America was discovered, not invented. But were Newton's laws discovered or invented? I'd saw the atom was discovered, not invented. And the speed of light?

As you can see, it's pretty hard to distinguish between the two, therefore you shouldn't call Einstein the **discoverer** nor the **inventor** of the Theory of Relativity, unless you want to take a side in the argument. I don't like "**father**" either: it's too partial. Maybe you should call him "**originator** of the Theory of Relativity".

Comment: One could equally well say that Darwin discovered evolution, since it operates whether or not humans are aware of it (and many still aren't!). As I've mentioned in other comments, I think it's important here to distinguish between theories and the phenomena they describe or explain; people create theories, but not the phenomena. Thus I think it's fair to say that, *e.g.*, Darwin created the *theory* of evolution, but discovered the *process* of natural selection.

Comment: For that matter, Columbus _discovered_ an already-existent America (the matter of other Europeans, and of course, native inhabitants, already have been there, aside). Einstein discovered the rules of Relativity, and formulated his famed Theory, but light already traveled at a fixed speed _c_, time and length and mass varied with speed, etc.

Comment: @Will and Phil: IMHO neither of you understand the difference between scientific discovery and invention. Which is fine: it's pretty off-topic here. But let me explain, anyway: Evolution or natural selection cannot be discovered, because they are not phenomena, just like capitalism is not a phenomenon, or love is not a phenomenon. The fact that people notice these things and give them names does not mean they are natural phenomena. Evolution and Natural Selection are something else: perhaps "explanatory principle" is the right term. They are not something that exists in nature (1)

Comment: @mobiusdumpling, that is a philosophical position on which we differ—it is not a fact.

Comment: (2) Similarly, it's questionable whether Einstein discovered the rules of Relativity. He described certain rules, that seem to well-approximate, in certain regimes, the way the universe works. This does not mean that the universe works according to these rules, it only means that these rules are **useful for us** when we wish to predict what the universe will do. Also, it's not clear whether the fact that light travels at a fixed speed is descovered or invented: it all depends at how "atomic" the concept of light is to the way the universe *actually* works, not only to the way we describe it.

Comment: @mobiusdumpling, these are fair points, but considering this is ELU, I'm looking for an English term that will efficiently convey my meaning, rather than a philosophically accurate one.

Comment: @Will: What are you referring to by *it* when you say "*it* is not a fact"? I can't think of any scientific school of thought that will claim that natural selection was discovered rather than invented. (Scientists often state such principles were "discovered" as a form of expression, but would actually correct themselves to "invented" when you ask them about it.) So unless you actually spent a lot of time thinking on the topic, I suggest that you think and read about it some more and I suspect you'll change your mind: I don't know of anyone who hasn't. It is a subtle topic, after all.

Comment: @Will Oh, sorry, I forgot you're the OP. Well, if you are willing to stand behind the claim that Darwin discovered Natural Selection, then surely the best choice for you would be to say that Einstein discovered Relativity: it seems to me to be the most accurate form under your approach. So then Einstein would be the "discoverer" of Relativity.

Comment: Oh, also for your question "What would be the term for a less renowned scientist who has proposed a more controversial theory?" I'd say that "creator" is the best term.

Comment: @mobiusdumpling, by “it” I meant your claim that evolution and natural selection are not natural phenomena. I seem to have had the opposite experience; every scientist I know would describe natural selection as a process that occurs whether humans are around or not, and most would then conclude that it was discovered (and not just as a form of expression). In any case, regarding the answer, I think “father” is the best term for a theory as famous as evolution or special relativity. “Creator” will have to do for the other case.

Comment: Well, it seems that Einstein would agree with me that his theory was invented, not discovered: http://amiquote.tumblr.com/post/2502848186/albert-einstein-on-the-physical-concepts-and
I'd think that if relativity was invented, then so was evolution.

Comment: @mobiusdumpling, see my first comment in this thread. IMHO, evolution is a theory and was invented, natural selection is a phenomenon and was discovered.

Comment: Relativity itself wasn't invented. It was observed, or possibly discovered (if it turns out to be real).  The theory describing it, on the other hand, is an original work; "invented" is an odd word for it IMO, but the theory was created, not discovered.  Same as how evolution was observed/discovered, but the theory describing it was created.

Comment: @cHao yes, that all makes sense. So relativity was observed. The theory of relativity was created or invented. Similarly, evolution and natural selection were observed, and the theories describing them was created or invented. I still have a problem with that, though: evolution and natural selection are organizing principles in the human mind, but they're not a natural phenomena, so I'm not even sure you can say they were "observed".

Comment: @cHao, precisely. This is what I said in the first comment on this answer.

Comment: @mobiusdumpling, at the risk of turning this comment thread into a chat thread: for me, the term “natural selection” denotes the *process*, which is certainly a natural phenomenon—just like *e.g.* erosion or oxidation.

Comment: An "organizing principle" can still be observable.  If i have a strain of bacteria, and i measure how long it takes the strain to develop an immunity to penicillin, i am observing natural selection.  The theory can define the phenomenon, but the phenomenon is defined entirely in terms of real-world happenings, and thus either does or doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, doesn't it sound natural something like

> Einstein is widely credited with having developed the [or you could even use "his"] theories on gravity and special relativity. Einstein's work largely influenced later work on physics such as the development of the atomic bomb and even metaphysical , such as in unified field, gravity, and black hole.

Wikipedia uses developed. That's not an authoritative source but I would say this is a question of style. *Inventor, discoverer, Patentor, creator*... they might all sound more or less natural depending on context, no?

If anything I think *father* maybe is a bit out there. For Einstein maybe, but that seems like a tenuous assertion generally speaking. But yet again, in the specific phrasing context of your question, that ("father") might be the best single-word choice... :/